# #1247 - Reference 'sid' not supported (reference to group function)

Tags: mysql

(reference to group function)--

```
SELECT `subject`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`student_id` SEPARATOR ',') as sid,
(SELECT concat(fname,' ',surname )
FROM student_registration 
WHERE student_id IN (sid) ) as name
FROM `email` GROUP BY `subject`
```

Answer (score 0):

try it and revert if you want something else-

```
SELECT a.`subject`, GROUP_CONCAT(a.student_id SEPARATOR ',') AS sid, CONCAT( b.fname,' ',b.surname ) AS 'name' 
FROM email AS a 
LEFT JOIN student_registration AS b ON b.student_id=a.student_id 
GROUP BY a.`subject`;
```